Multi-objective structural causal bandits
I am reading the paper "Structural Causal Bandits: Where to intervene?" by Lee & Bareinboim (2018). Here is a link: https://papers.nips.cc/paper_files/paper/2018/file/c0a271bc0ecb776a094786474322cb82-Paper.pdf
I am trying to expand their results to the multi-objective case, that is, there are multiple target variables $\mathbf{Y} = \{Y_1,\dots,Y_m \}$. Here is a reformulation the definition for possibly-optimal minimal intervention sets:
Definition.     Given $\langle \mathcal{G}, \mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{X} \rangle$, let $\mathbf{X}_s$ be a minimal intervention set and $\mathbf{x}_s \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbf{X}_s)$. Then, $\mathbf{X}_s$ is called possibly-optimal if there is no other minimal intervention set $\mathbf{X}_s'$ and $\mathbf{x}_s' \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbf{X}_s')$ with $\mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s = \mathbf{x}_s)] \geq \mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s'=\mathbf{x}_s')]$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s = \mathbf{x}_s)] > \mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s'=\mathbf{x}_s')]$ for at least one $1 \leq i \leq m$, for some SCM conforming to $\mathcal{G}$.
I want to prove proposition 2 for the multi objective case. Here is a reformulation of the proposition in the multi-objective case and the proof I have come up with:
Proposition. If no $Y_i$ is confounded with $\text{an}(Y_i)_{\mathcal{G}}$ via unobserved confounders, then $\text{pa}(\mathbf{Y})_{\mathcal{G}}$ is the only possibly-optimal minimal intervention set.
Proof.
Let $\mathbf{X}_s$ be a minimal intervention set and $\mathbf{x}_s \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbf{X}_s)$. Let $\mathbf{X}_s' = \text{pa}(\mathbf{Y})_{\mathcal{G}}$ and $\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{X}_s' \backslash (\mathbf{X}_s \cap \mathbf{X}_s')$. Then, for all $i=1,\dots,m$ it holds
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s=\mathbf{x}_s)] &= \int_{\mathcal{D}(\mathbf{Z})} \mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s=\mathbf{x}_s), \mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{z}] P(\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{z} | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s=\mathbf{x}_s)) d\mathbf{z}  \\
    &= \int_{\mathcal{D}(\mathbf{Z})} \mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s=\mathbf{x}_s, \mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{z})] P(\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{z} | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s=\mathbf{x}_s)) d\mathbf{z}\\
    &= \int_{\mathcal{D}(\mathbf{Z})} \mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s \cap \mathbf{X}_s'=\mathbf{x}_s[\mathbf{X}_s'], \mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{z})] P(\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{z} | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s=\mathbf{x}_s)) d\mathbf{z} \\
    & \geq \int_{\mathcal{D}(\mathbf{Z})} \mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s'=\mathbf{x}_s')] P(\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{z} | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s=\mathbf{x}_s)) d\mathbf{z}\\
    & = \mathbb{E}[Y_i | \text{do}(\mathbf{X}_s'=\mathbf{x}_s')]
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{x}_s' \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbf{X}_s')$ is a non-dominated intervention value. Note that the second equality is derived through the second rule of do-calculus and the third equality assumes that $Y_i$ is not confounded with $\text{an}(Y_i)_{\mathcal{G}}$ via unobserved confounders.
If $\mathbf{X}_s \neq \text{pa}(\mathbf{Y})_{\mathcal{G}}$, it is possible to construct an \textsc{scm}, conforming to $\mathcal{G}$, such that strict inequality holds for at least one $Y_i$. This shows that $\mathbf{X}_s'$ can be the only possibly-optimal minimal intervention set.
Unfortunately, I am pretty sure that this proof is incorrect due to the fact that the inequality does not need to hold for all $\mathbf
{z} \in \mathbf{Z}$. Can someone help me? That would be highly appreciated!

A question, just to be sure: are higher values of the outcomes $Y_i$ more or less desirable? The inequality in the definition seems to suggest that lower values are more deniable, so action $X$ is optimal if no other action $X'$ provides a lower value.

@JohandeAguas Yes, exactly. Lower outcomes  are more desirable! Thanks for the follow up :)

desirable, sorry... Now, maybe I am missing something, but I believe the inequality appears when you replace a intervention on the parent set at any values ($x_s[X'_s],z$) by an intervention on the best value (${x'}^{}_s$), which is a constant and leaves out the integral (which integrates to one). In the end you get $\mathbb{E}[Y_i\mid \text{do}(X'_s={x'}^{*}_s)]$, so the only intervention set is the parent set.

@JohandeAguas The problem, I believe, is that there is no universal best value $(x'^*_s)$ over all $z$ because we are in the multi-objective case and want to find non-dominant trade-offs between the $Y_i$ (just like in multi-objective optimisation).

Right. Without a total order or a real-valued utility function, a uniformly optimal action might not exist. Could you introduce a total order $\preceq$ on the Cartesian product of $Y$, such as the lexicographic order? This would allow you to construct the optimal action value by sequentially determining the optimal action value for each outcome, following the specified priority order.

@JohandeAguas oh that makes sense! I am a bit lost on how to adapt the definition here. I am afraid taking averages across all $Y_i$ does not make much sense but I don't know how to proceed with that. Can you help me out? :(
